# How to extract direct link to Youtube video?

Tags: video, download, youtube-dl

I'm currently downloading videos using Youtube-dl, but I don't want to download videos on server, but only extract direct link to video file and arrange browser to start download. Can anybody show me direction to extracting link to Youtube files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--get-url` or `-g`:

```
youtube-dl --get-url 2eBZqmL8ehg
```